# 500 Internal Server Error after 30 minutes in WebSphere8

Tags: spring-batch, websphere-8

I developed an Spring Batch application, and hosted in a corporative WebSphere 8.5.15 server. This application some rest endpoints for execute diferents jobs that basically do calls to stored procedures and execute multiples database querys.

I call the endpoint using curl like this:

```
curl --insecure --request GET 'https://mycorp.server.com:1443/batch/api/job/job1?odate=050820'
```

After 30 minutes of execution i am getting following response:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>

<head>
    <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
    <p>The server encountered an internal error or
        misconfiguration and was unable to complete
        your request.</p>
    <p>Please contact the server administrator at
        ped@mycorp.server.com to inform them of the time this error occurred,
        and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
    <p>More information about this error may be available
        in the server error log.</p>
    <p>Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error
        error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

I been tried many times the execution and always receiving same error "500 Internal Server Error" after 30 minutes of processing the request. In the logs file all seems to be ok, no errors or exceptions reported.

Comment: `In the logs file all seems to be ok, no errors or exceptions reported.`: There should be an error somewhere, either in the batch job's code or in the REST controller that launches it. Make sure to set the log level to debug and check all the logs of your app.

Comment: No errors in the server standard log, investigating more there were error reported in the Websphere plugins logs. Seems to be ServerIOTimeout configuration in the plugin configuration

Answer (score -1):

It's a common occurrence for a server to occasionally not respond properly (a 500 error). You should work around this by telling your program to sleep for a few seconds when you get there error, And then continue any calls to the server as necessary. Essentially, just acknowledge you'll run into issues like this and work around them the best you can.